# Performing linear search on randomized array

Tags: c#

I am trying to perform a linear search on some randomized array, but just cant see where the code gets stuck. Its a simple BigONotation algorithm test that I am currently learning and messed up somewhere. I am using a text editor for my coding. Can I get some help with this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace TheBigONotations
{
    public class BigONotations
    {
        ///<properties>Class Properties</properties>
        private int[] theArray;
        private int arraySize;
        private int itemsInArray = 0;
        DateTime startTime;
        DateTime endTime;

        public BigONotations(int size)
        {
            arraySize = size;
            theArray = new int[size];
        }
        ///<order>O(1)</order>
        public void addItemToArray(int newItem)
        {
            theArray[itemsInArray++] = newItem;
        }
        ///<order>O(n)</order>
        public void linearSearch(int value)
        {
            bool valueInArray = false;
            string indexsWithValue = "";

            startTime = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                if (theArray[i] == value)
                {
                    valueInArray = true;
                    indexsWithValue += i + " ";
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Value found: " + valueInArray);

            endTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Linear Search took "+(endTime - startTime) );
        }

        ///<order>O(n^2)</order>
        public void BinarySearch()
        {

        }
        ///<order>O(n)</order>

        ///<order>O(n)</order>

        ///<order>O(n)</order>

        public void generateRandomArray()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                theArray[i] = (int)(rnd.Next() * 1000) + 10;
            }
            itemInArray = arraySize - 1;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {

            BigONotations algoTest1 = new BigONotations(100000);
            algoTest1.generateRandomArray();

            BigONotations algoTest2 = new BigONotations(200000);
            algoTest2.generateRandomArray();

            BigONotations algoTest3 = new BigONotations(300000);
            algoTest3.generateRandomArray();

            BigONotations algoTest4 = new BigONotations(400000);
            algoTest4.generateRandomArray();

            BigONotations algoTest5 = new BigONotations(500000);
            algoTest5.generateRandomArray();

            algoTest2.linearSearch(20);
            algoTest3.linearSearch(20);
            algoTest4.linearSearch(20);


        }
    }
}
```

I put all information in the code but had some error and cant see exactly where it is.

Comment: Output - `Console.WriteLine("Value found: " + valueInArray);` can be very *slow* and distort the linear picture. Note, that `endTime = DateTime.Now;` is *after* `Console.WriteLine...`

Comment: Side-note: use the `StopWatch`-class instead of `DateTime` math if you want to measure the time accurately.

Comment: You, probably, want to add `break` after `valueInArray = true;` since you don't use `indexsWithValue`

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is because `itemInArray` inside `generateRandomArray()` function is not declared. Perhaps you meant `itemsInArray`?

String addition (with `+` and `+=` operator) for too many results might be taking long time during `linearSearch()`. Consider using [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) which is significantly faster and more memory efficient.

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// ...

// Let's say "i" is an integer.
sb.Append(i.ToString());
sb.Append(" ");
// ...

Console.WriteLine("Indexes: " + sb.ToString());
```